# Solving the Expression_Problem in computer game design

Tags: haskell, agda

No other game impressed me more than [ADOM](http://www.ancientdomainsofmystery.com/) because of its almost endless ways you can interact with its world. To name a few: If you have waterproof blankets your items will not rust in rain, you can cut trees to build a bridge, dip weapons into potions, kick locked doors etc.

With such complexity of interactions each new feature may require refactoring, recompilation, then cause broken tests, bugs etc. This seems to be an interesting case of the Expression Problem.

**The Question:**

Can solution to Expression Problem be expressed in Agda or Haskell as a reusable library or a design pattern?

Comment: Your question `they look quite complex for someone not having good theoretical background` has the answer i.e gain the theoretical knowledge to use those solutions. By the way, languages are not powerful, concepts are .. just saying :)